# Can the U.S. president suspend any government officials given a good enough reason?

Tags: united-states, democracy, government

> Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu on Sunday suspended the
> minister from a far-right party in the coalition government and from
> cabinet meetings “until further notice”.

https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/11/7/israels-nuclear-option-remark-raises-huge-number-of-questions-russia

Can the U.S. president suspend any government officials given a good enough reason? I was surprised that it was the Prime Minister himself who suspended, you would think that a democratic government would have a sort of committee to have the final words on this, is this something that's allowed in the U.S.? I am thinking it might be also true in the U.S. given that the official had committed an action terrible enough to warrant it.

Comment: Israel is a parliamentary democracy where ministers can be removed or appointed by the PM (actually the cabinet, usually in consultation with party leaders / coalition leaders).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define "Government Official"....

In the US system the President is head of the executive.  He can appoint to the cabinet (with the advice and consent of the senate) and he can remove (on his own authority) members of the executive. He can fire members of his cabinet on a whim.

He can suspend or fire other senior officials such as Ambassadors. But he doesn't (in general) suspend minor government employees, such as postal workers or national park rangers.

He can't appoint or suspend positions in the House or Senate. He can't remove the Speaker of the House, or the chair of a Senate committee.

The big difference is that in the US system, members of the Cabinet are explicitly not Representatives or Senators.  In a Parliamentary system, members of the Cabinet must be Representatives or Senators (however these are named in a particular country)

I'm not sure how you imagine "democracy" to work.  The Cabinet ***is*** "some sort of committee".  It is chaired by the Prime Minister, and it is the Prime Minister acting as the head of the Cabinet who suspended a minister who had made an unacceptable comment in public.

Comment: On a related issue -- all these Presidential appointments require Senate confirmation. But  AFAIK the Senate can't revoke their confirmation -- they can't fire an ambassador, cabinet member, etc.

Comment: Or are they all subject to impeachment?

Comment: usually members of a parliament are called MPs in English.  On a separate note, Israel had a separate election for Prime Minister 1996-2001 (and the 1st time it was held, it was won by Netanyahu, whose party did not win the plurality of the parliament) before abandoning it.  They toy with the idea of bringing it back sometimes.

Comment: "But he doesn't (in general) suspend minor government employees, such as postal workers or national park rangers." It isn't just that he doesn't, he can't. Political appointees have little authority to fire employees who are part of the civil service system without good cause which is a quite high bar. Some government employees (e.g. judges and employees of independent agencies) aren't even under his direct line authority to direct and control.

Comment: @Barmar Basically all government employees are subject to impeachment, although in practice the process has been used very sparingly, mostly for judges who can't be removed from office by other means.

Comment: "In a Parliamentary system, members of the Cabinet must be Representatives or Senators" - I think this would surprise much of mainland Europe. There are even countries where it's constitutionally forbidden. Parliament holds the cabinet accountable, and there's a conflict of interest if you would oversee yourself.

Comment: @ohwilleke the President is not a political appointee.  He is the only person in the executive branch (with the technical exception of the VP) who answers directly to the voters.

Comment: @wrod The President has no more legal authority to fire civil servants than political appointees do. Preventing the President or someone acting at his direction from firing a government employee who isn't a political appointee for political reasons is one of the primary reasons that the civil service system exists. This isn't unusual. It is true in France. It is true in almost every Western style democratic government. In the U.S., at least, the President is not the CEO of the federal government. Congress, civil service rules, government contracting rules, the APA constrain him at every step.

Comment: @ohwilleke right, but the US government is governed by the US Constitution rather than the Western tradition at large.  I am not arguing that he *should* be able to fire civil servants, only that the reason for his lacking such authority cannot be the fact that political appointees cannot fire civil servants at will because the President is not a political appointee.  Some of that diminished authority (for the President) is self-imposed.  Like the unionization rules were a result of Carter asking for it.  Ultimately, the civil servants cannot be *entirely* without voter-imposed oversight.